# How to move text line to the top of <div>

Tags: html, css

Regarding step 1 as depicted by the image, how can I move the first line upwards "My first item", so that the proceeding line is just beneath it (as you can see to the right)?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/simon-parker-the-decoder/pen/abZXPpR)

[image: Image of how the solution is suppose to look like]

Thank you

**Html**

```
<div class="list">
    <div>My first item <br>
      My first item continued
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>My second item</div>
    <br>
    <div>My third item</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.list {
  counter-reset: list-number;
}
div.list div:before {
  counter-increment: list-number;
  content: counter(list-number);
  
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  width:35px;
  height:35px;
  display:inline-flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size:16px;
  background-color:#d7385e;
  border-radius:50%;
  color:#fff;
}

 div.list div {
   color: purple;
 }
```

Comment: Numbered lists should be `<ol><li>`, not `<div>`. Why are you using `<div>`?

Comment: Tip: pseudo-elements have double-colon prefixes, e.g. `div::before`, not `div:before`. Browsers will accept single-colons for `:before` and `:after` but that's for backwards-compatibility - so you should change your CSS to use `::before`.

Comment: add float:left to pseudo element

Comment: @Dai flexbox/CSS grid or any other technique cannot achieve text *floating* around element like shown in his second screenshot so float is the only solution for *floating* behavior. Float will never die and should never die because it can achieve things you will never be able to do with flexbox or CSS grid.

Answer (score 1):

just add `dispaly:flex`

```css
div.list {
  counter-reset: list-number;
}

.list > div::before {
  counter-increment: list-number;
  content: counter(list-number);
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #d7385e;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
}

.list > div {
  display: flex;
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div>My first item <br> My first item continued
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>My second item</div>
  <br>
  <div>My third item</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be best to change the structure of your HTML for something like this, but here's a solution with only changing the CSS.

Add `display: flex;` to your `div.list div`

```css
div.list {
  counter-reset: list-number;
}

div.list div::before {
  counter-increment: list-number;
  content: counter(list-number);
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #d7385e;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
}

div.list div {
  color: purple;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div>My first item <br> My first item continued
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>My second item</div>
  <br>
  <div>My third item</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add flexbox property `display:flex`

```css
div.list {
  counter-reset: list-number;
}
div.list div:before {
  counter-increment: list-number;
  content: counter(list-number);
  
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  width:35px;
  height:35px;
  display:inline-flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size:16px;
  background-color:#d7385e;
  border-radius:50%;
  color:#fff;
}

 div.list div {
   color: purple;
   display: flex;
 }
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div>My first item <br>
    My first item continued
  </div><br>
  <div>My second item</div><br>
  <div>My third item</div>
</div>
```

or

```css
div.list {
      counter-reset: list-number;
    }
    div.list div:before {
      counter-increment: list-number;
      content: counter(list-number);
      
      margin-right: 10px;
      margin-bottom:10px;
      width:35px;
      height:35px;
      display:inline-flex;
      align-items:center;
      justify-content: center;
      font-size:16px;
      background-color:#d7385e;
      border-radius:50%;
      color:#fff;
    }

     div.list div {
       color: purple;
       display: flex;
       margin: 15px 0px;
     }
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div>My first item <br> My first item continued</div>
  <div>My second item</div>
  <div>My third item</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there was some confusion as to what the solution should look like based on the common answer of adding `display: flex;` to my `div.list div`

When in fact, this does not make the lines wrap around the number circle as displayed in the image of what the result should be.

Thanks to the comment by @TemaniAfif, with the solution of "add `float:left;` to pseudo element", lines now wrap around the number circle.

Nevertheless, thanks for all your guys' input.

[image: Comparison of the results of the solutions given]